# Use pretrained pytorch model in C?

Tags: c, pytorch, pre-trained-model

So I have a pretrained pytorch model, I have saved both the model and the parameters just in case, but I need to use this model in C or C++ code, anybody know how I can do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: look at `torch.onnx` to convert it to Caffe2, which has a C++ API.

Comment: @Rael please tell me what you did after i wanna do same thing as you.

Answer (score 0):

Try pytorch 1.0, which include a c++ library. The model could be exported to torch script format and be loaded in C++, check here https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html

Comment: but according to what i have see this option is not really covered i mean their is no tuto that show how to do so for many model  except this one u shared here :!.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, try pytorch package in PPA of [ppa:nnstreamer/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nnstreamer/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).
In this Ubuntu pytorch package, there are header files and pkgconfig (.pc) file that helps building C/C++ programs using pytorch.
If you want more simple ways to invoke pytorch/caffe2 models from C/C++ program, you may use C/API of nnstreamer or approach nnstreamer w/ GStreamer API as well.

To install nnstreamer or C-friendly pytorch (or tensorflow), use PPA by:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nnstreamer/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ suto apt-get install ${whateveryouwant}
```

Candidates for ${whateveryouwant}: nnstreamer,  nnstreamer-dev, nnstreamer-pytorch

If you want to access pytorch directly from your C code without using nnstreamer, you may refer to pytorch-wrapper of nnstreamer at: https://github.com/nnsuite/nnstreamer/blob/master/ext/nnstreamer/tensor_filter/tensor_filter_pytorch_core.cc